# Should I use a separate Socket.IO server or not?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm currently working on a Node.JS application which needs to be highly scalable for use in a particularly popular website.

Currently, the Node.JS and Socket.IO server is running as one application meaning to deploy a new release I just restart the server.

I've had suggestions to make the Socket.IO server separate to the Node.JS app running the site but feel as though this could make keeping the Javascript from the web server and Socket.IO server in sync tricky.

What should I do?